# Swagger UI passing authentication token to API call

Tags: python, rest, flask, swagger

The first call is to generate a token based on user name and password. All remaining calls in my REST API project need token generated by the first call to do token validation first, if the token is valid, I continue to process the requested REST resources; if it's invalid, reject the request.

I am using Python Flask, how I set that token for all others calls using Swagger UI? Is it appropriate to set the token in the header?